# Firefox addon stops working when packed in to xpi

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I've made an extension using the addon sdk, and it works as expected when running with `cfx run`. But when I pack it in to an xpi using `cfx xpi` and install it - it stops working - no scripts are injected and I'm not even getting any errors :(

Any ideas on how to fix this, or how can I debug this kind of issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution. I'm simply using the .xpi that Firefox packs automatically for testing. In order to use it, run the `cfx run` with the `-p` parameter pointing to a profile you've created, like this:

`cfx run -p <your path to firefox>\profiles\someprofile`

After running, go the that profile's folder, and find in there the *extensions* folder, it should be something like this:

`<your path to firefox>\profiles\someprofile\extensions`

In there you'll have your addon with a weird file name and an `.xpi` file extension. Rename it to anything you want, leaving the `.xpi` file extension intact.

**EDIT:**
Apparently the `cfx xpi` command strips *by default* what it thinks to be unused modules and `.js` files. To avoid this you need to run it with a special flag, like this: `cfx xpi --no-strip-xpi`

Comment: Are you using any third-party modules? As a maintainer of a third-party Jetpack module, I discovered an issue that affects packages: `cfx run` works as intended, whereas the resulting xpi file of `cfx xpi` is broken: https://github.com/Rob--W/browser-action-jplib/issues/1

Comment: @RobW nope, not using any external modules

Comment: Saved my day... The command stripping files by default is frustrating.

Answer (score 0):

- try to uninstall and then reinstall the addon you developed
- try installing the addon on another firefox build(aurora, nightly, beta)

Comment: Did uninstall/reinstall. Didn't help. What am I supposed to learn from installing it on other builds of firefox?

Answer (score 0):

What I do in such a case:

1. Disable extension from Addon Manager.
2. Restart Firefox.
3. Open Console Window (Ctrl+Shift+J)
4. Enable extension and watch for errors in Console.

Sometimes startup errors do not appear in Console window unless it is already opened.

Answer (score 0):

[Resetting firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) worked for me.

1. Type `about:troubleshooting` in your address bar
2. Click the `reset firefox` button in the upper-right hand corner of the Troubleshooting page
   [image: screenshot]
   <sub>(source: [mozilla.net](https://support.cdn.mozilla.net/media/uploads/gallery/images/2014-03-20-11-32-20-5e74fe.png))</sub>
3. Confirm your action

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: the essential part of the answer: resetting firefox

Comment: I don't know who downvoted this. I had the exact same problem, as the MeLight, who asked this question. And I read his answer and remembered that I changed firefox settings before, as I was working on an outdated tutorial. So I googled and found the solution to reset firefox. It worked. It is the right answer to this question. He who downvoted this answer has no clue about this here at all!

Comment: When I reviewed your answer it was link only. By the way i am not the downvoter.

Comment: @ShreyosAdikari thx for the reply. But my answer was never link only. I could have just written:" Resetting firefox worked for me." without the link. This is the actual answer here. The link is not the answer. It is just helpful to get it done.